# Strange behaviour of sejda-console in batch for loop

Tags: batch-file, sejda

I try to write a wrapper script for songbook generation using lilypond, latex and sejda-console (for the pdf part). Everything works so far, but I have a problem with sejda that is giving me nuts.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
for %%i in (%f%) do (
    sejda-console.bat extractbybookmarks -f ".\%%~ni.pdf" -o "export\%%~ni\%title%.pdf" -l 2 -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -e "%title%" --overwrite
)
```

where f is a ";"-separated list of files. This command works for the first file, but fails for all others. I can't find any difference between the commands that sejda receives. Here is my console output:

```
make_sheet.bat -t "Live it up" --supress *.lytex
Configuring Sejda 3.2.30
Starting execution with arguments: 'extractbybookmarks -f .\book_drums.pdf -o export\book_drums\Live it up.pdf -l 2 -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -e Live it up --overwrite'
Java version: '1.8.0_151'
Validating parameters.
Starting task (org.sejda.impl.sambox.ExtractByOutlineTask@28701274) execution.
Opening C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\out\.\book_drums.pdf
Retrieving outline information for level 2 and match regex Live it up
Starting extraction by outline, level 2 and match regex Live it up
Found 0 inherited images and 0 inherited fonts potentially unused
Starting extracting Live it up pages 9 9
Created output temporary buffer C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\out\export\book_drums\.sejdaTmp2789047920522272436.tmp
Appended relevant outline items
Filtering annotations
Skipped acroform merge, nothing to merge
Ending extracting Live it up
Task progress: 0% done
Moving C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\out\export\book_drums\.sejdaTmp2789047920522272436.tmp to C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\out\export\book_drums\Live it up.pdf.
Extraction completed and outputs written to org.sejda.model.output.FileOrDirectoryTaskOutput@478190fc[C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample\out\export\book_drums\Live it up.pdf]
Task (org.sejda.impl.sambox.ExtractByOutlineTask@28701274) executed in 0 seconds
Completed execution

C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample>(sejda-console.bat extractbybookmarks -f ".\book_general.pdf" -o "export\book_general\Live it up.pdf" -l 2 -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -e "Live it up" --overwrite )
Configuring Sejda 3.2.30
Starting execution with arguments: 'extractbybookmarks -f .\book_general.pdf -o export\book_general\Live it up.pdf -l 2 -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -e Live it up --overwrite'
Java version: '1.8.0_151'
Invalid value (File '.\book_general.pdf' does not exist): --files -f value... : pdf files to operate on. A list of existing pdf files (EX. -f /tmp/file1.pdf or -f /tmp/password_protected_file2.pdf:secret123) (required)
Invalid value (File '.\book_general.pdf' does not exist): --files -f value... : pdf files to operate on. A list of existing pdf files (EX. -f /tmp/file1.pdf or -f /tmp/password_protected_file2.pdf:secret123) (required)

C:\Users\skr1_\Desktop\Tools\Songbook\Sample>(sejda-console.bat extractbybookmarks -f ".\book_guitar.pdf" -o "export\book_guitar\Live it up.pdf" -l 2 -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -e "Live it up" --overwrite )
Configuring Sejda 3.2.30
Starting execution with arguments: 'extractbybookmarks -f .\book_guitar.pdf -o export\book_guitar\Live it up.pdf -l 2 -p [BOOKMARK_NAME] -e Live it up --overwrite'
Java version: '1.8.0_151'
Invalid value (File '.\book_guitar.pdf' does not exist): --files -f value... : pdf files to operate on. A list of existing pdf files (EX. -f /tmp/file1.pdf or -f /tmp/password_protected_file2.pdf:secret123) (required)
Invalid value (File '.\book_guitar.pdf' does not exist): --files -f value... : pdf files to operate on. A list of existing pdf files (EX. -f /tmp/file1.pdf or -f /tmp/password_protected_file2.pdf:secret123) (required)
```

Even worse, if I copy the commands that sejda receives and paste them as arguments for a new command, everything works fine.
I suspect that something is happening with the working directory in between, but I don't get it.

Also, note that the output includes the command for subsequent passes of the for-loop (starting with "(sejda-console.bat ...") though echo is off. It is not included for the first run, however.

I'm not an expert with programming, especially not with batch, and any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that `sejda.bat` is changing the current directory.

Try

```
pushd
call sejda.bat ...
popd
```